# Ability to use git and branching with code on the server

Tags: server

Is it possible for your server to have git and then have the ability to branch off and then able to view it in the browser so for example if I go to site.com/branch/new-branch then the changes I make to the branch will show up there. So kind of the way I would have it in my localhost, but on the server. If that makes sense.